# Darn linker errors XCode 4.3--algorithm to solve them?

Tags: xcode, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate_Shared", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate_iPad in AppDelegate_iPad.o
>          "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate_Shared", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate_iPad in AppDelegate_iPad.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Hello, this is a straight up AppDelegate, and I'm getting this error. Any ideas? There's no library to link to or anything.  I've seen these errors time and time again in XCode, but the causes have ranged from a libxml2 library being not right (needed libxml2.7.3), to just something odd in XCode itself.  No idea what to do next, but obviously would like the program to compile.  Thanks!

Comment: I spent two weeks debugging a linker error once. I hate them.

Comment: Thanks, makes me feel better. I've already spent 1 week in the past, and the solution was completely random.

Comment: Mine turned out to be an incorrectly written == operator. Was generating a mismatch Low/Hi something. Had to compile 118 .o files with varying levels of optimization, then ran a script to try linking with all non-optimized except one and report the failures. Then comment half the file, compile, comment other half, compile, comment quarter... etc to narrow it down to the offending statement. THEN I had to figure out why this innocuous compare to NULL was causing the linker error. Evil, evil, evil. Even looked at the source for ld at one point!

Comment: Well, the solution in this case, was that AppDelegate_shared.m was not for some reason in the the Target's compile sources. I 100% fully blame XCode for this. 100%. I dragged in my AppDelegate to the project, and STILL it was not added to the compile sources list. This should happen automatically.  Other people will have this issue too.  So click on your Target (Go to your project icon, and look for your target usually with your app icon.  Click once on it. Then look for build phases, and you'll see Compile Sources.  Add your "missing" .m file there and at least this worked for me.

Comment: Ooh. Nasty. Well, write your comment up as an answer, then accept it after the timer will let you do that.

Comment: @user798719 Not if the add to target checkbox was unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

same here. thanks for the answer.

I had just (literally 30 seconds ago) dragged the files in.
I used the same files in other projects no problem.
got this linker error (updated to XCode 4.3 yesterday)
and same problem, the .m file was checked for the Test target membership, but NOT the app target.

possibly a 4.3 bug. it seems it is defaulting to adding dragged in files to the test build and not the app build.

thanks... you helped me find it very fast. I was not looking forward to that.